# What makes a wxpython TextCtrl fill horizontally

Tags: python, wxpython, fill, sizer

I have a `TextCtrl` in a horizontal `BoxSizer`.  It is added with a weight of 1 (next to a button with a weight of 0).  When I run the program, the `TextCtrl` will remain at a fixed width with empty space next to it, regardless of the size of the window.  Why?

Here is the code:

```
wxapp = wx.App()
wxFrame = wx.Frame(None, -1 , 'Switch Time Zones', (0,0),(340,64))
wxFrame.Centre()
mainBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
wxFrame.SetSizer(mainBox)

...#A few things are added to mainBox

outputBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
mainBox.Add(outputBox, 1, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)

...#A few things are added to other boxes

submitButton = wx.Button(wxFrame,label='solve:')
outputBox.Add(submitButton,0)
outputText = wx.TextCtrl(wxFrame)
outputText.SetEditable(False)
outputBox.Add(outputText,1)

wxFrame.Show()
wxapp.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mainBox.Add(outputBox, 1, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND)
```

Comment: You're right. Noticed this about a minute after posting the question. The TextCtrl filled the horizontal sizer, but the horizontal sizer wasn't filling the vertical sizer. Thanks (also, impressive response time).